# Name of this homomorphism like mapping

Tags: group-homomorphism, ring-homomorphism

**edited:**
I have a problem in which, a map $f: (S, \star)\rightarrow   (S', \cdot)$ such that $f(e)=e'$, where $e$ and $e'$ are identities of $S$ and $S'$, respectively,  and for all $x, y\in S$, we get $f(x\star y)=f(p)\cdot f(q)$, where $p, q\in S$ and $f(p), f(q)\in S'$. Can such mappings be called a homomorphism? If not, is there any name for such mappings?

> **Note** $p$ and $q$ may be distinct from $x$ and $y$, respectively. Whereas, in standard definition of a monoid homomorphism, we have for all $x, y\in S$ implies that $f(x\star y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$.

Comment: Wait,are both stars for same operations what do you mean by x,y,p,q suddenly changing.I don't think it is homomorphism or something.Make the meaning clear first.

Comment: @Kishalay Sarkar Yes the star operations in both sets are same $p$ and $q$ may or may not be the same as $x$ and $y$

Comment: What do you mean by saying the star operations are the same, when the sets they're defined on are different? If they're restrictions of the same operation to subsets of some ambient set, then $f$ is nothing more or less than homomorphism of binary structures (and, incidentally, you can prove that $e=e'$).

Comment: So *any* map from a monoid to itself, as long as it fixes the identity,  would match the description? (Pick $p=e$ and $q=x\star y$)

Comment: @Clive Newstead I meant the operations on $S$ and $S'$ are same. The problem here is $f(x\star y)=f(p)\f(q)$, where $p$ and $q$ may be different from $x$ and $y$, respectively. Whereas, in standard definition definition of a monoid homomorphism, we have for all $x, y\in S$ implies that $f(x\star y)=f(x)\star f(y)$.

Comment: @gete: My question has nothing to do with $f$. What do you mean when you say 'the operations on $S$ and $S'$ are the same'? What if $S$ is the set of integers and $S'$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, for example—how could $\star$ be 'the same' on these two sets? If you're saying $\star$ is the same on $S$ as $S'$, then you're saying something about the relationship between $S$ and $S'$ (e.g. that they're equal, or they're both subsets of some larger ambient set on which $\star$ is defined), but I don't know what that relationship is.

Comment: @Clive Newstead Ok. I consider that $S$ is a set of simple graphs and $S'$ is the set of complete graphs where $f$ is defined as $f(G_i)=K_{\chi(G_i)}$, where $K_{\chi(G_i)}$ is a complete graph with number of vertices=the chromatic graph of $G_i$. The operations on $S$ and $S'$ are graph union denoted by $\star=\cup$. This is a big problem. But what i wanted to know here is that can a map satisfying $f(x\star y)=f(p)\star f(q)$,  where $x$ and $y$  may be distinct from $p$ and $q$ be called a homomorphism? Ok let's take two different operations namely, $\star$ and $\cdot$  instead.

Comment: @Clive Newstead Let's say the operations on $S$ and $S'$ are different namely, $\star$ is defined on $S$ and $\cdot$ on $S'$ such that $f(x\star y)=f(p)\cdot f(q)$ where $x$ and $y$ may be distinct from $p$ and $q$, respectively. Can $f$ be a homomorphism now?

Comment: @gete: Yes, it can be a homomorphism. For example define $f : (\mathbb{Z}, +) \to (\mathbb{Z}_2, +_2)$, where $+_2$ denotes 'addition modulo $2$', by letting $f(k)$ be the remainder of $k$ when divided by $2$ (so is $0$ when $k$ is even, and $1$ when $k$ is odd). This function $f$ is a homomorphism and, for example, we have $f(1+5) = f(3) +_2 f(7)$. Most non-injective homomorphisms will satisfy the property you're asking about.

Comment: @Clive Newstead Ok. You could post it as answer also. Thanks

Comment: @gete: Done! $~~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posting more or less what I said in the comment thread, plus a bit extra.]

Any homomorphism $f : (S, \star) \to (S', \cdot)$ satisfies the property in your question: just take $p=x$ and $q=y$.

When $f$ is not injective, it's possible to have $f(x \star y) = f(p) \cdot f(q)$ with $p \ne x$ and $q \ne y$—as long as $f(x)=f(p)$ and $f(y)=f(q)$ you're good to go. For example, for example the homomorphism
$$f : (\mathbb{Z}, +) \to (\mathbb{Z}_2, +_2)$$
given by $f(n) = (n \bmod 2)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $f(1+5) = f(3) +_2 f(7)$.

However, if your definition is:

> A function $f : (S, \star) \to (S', \cdot)$ is a [*insert name of notion here*] if, for all $x,y \in S$, there exist $p,q \in S$ such that $f(x \star y) = f(p) \cdot f(q)$.

Then such functions might not be homomorphisms. As a trivial example, define $f : (\mathbb{Z}_3, +_3) \to (\mathbb{Z}, +)$ by $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=1$. This is most certainly not a homomorphism, since for example
$$f(2 +_3 2) = f(1) = 0 \quad \text{but} \quad f(2) + f(2) = 1+1 = 2$$
But it satisfies the property in your question, since the only values of $f$ are $0=f(0)+f(0)$ and $1 = f(0)+f(2)$.

I can't see a reason why such functions would be useful, so I very much doubt they have a name.